# Good books on relation theory

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know any good books on relation theory? By "relation", I mean a subset of a cartesian power of a set $S$. I would really love to read some good books on the theory of relations.

Comment: See [Branch of math studying relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100256/13130).

Comment: This question is a bit broad. What sorts of questions are you interested in? E.g. are you looking for a text on **relation(al) algebra(s)**?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am interested in the theory behind relations, mostly binary relations, and various subtypes of binary relations, such as transitive relations, euclidean relations, circular relations, etc.

Comment: @user107952 I guess I'm still not exactly clear on what you're asking. For example, under one interpretation this is just a subfield of graph theory (namely the part studying directed graphs with no two edges having the same source and target), but presumably "graph theory" is a bit too broad. Can you clarify what sort of question you're interested in?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am interested in books or texts that define various subclasses of binary relations, and proves various things about those classes of relations, for example, that every reflexive and euclidean relation is an equivalence relation (that is just one example). It doesn't have to be a book, it could just be a journal article.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00370681 "The origin of relation algebras in the development and axiomatization of the calculus of relations" Seems to be a good introduction